# Find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} \frac{x^2 - 9}{x - 3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} \frac{x^2 - 9}{x - 3}$

My professor showed us a few ways to compute the limit

1) Factor the numerator

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} \frac{x^2 - 9}{x - 3} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 3} (x + 3) = 6$

2)

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} \frac{f(x) - f(3)}{x - 3} = f'(3) = 2 \cdot 3 = 6$

Here I'm a little confused, where did $\frac{f(x) - f(3)}{x - 3}$ come from? Also, how does $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} f(x) = f'(3)$?

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ here. It's not that $\lim_{x\to 3}f(x) = f'(3)$, it is rather that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(x_0)$$ by the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ,,, $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(x)$, isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here We have taken $f(x)=x^2$. 
And as you know $\dfrac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)- f(a)}{x - a}$. And your professor used this.. So, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} x^2=a^2=f(a)=f'(x).$ Can you understand? Be fearless for asking.

Comment: I see. So this has no relation to finding the limit of $\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}$ as $x \rightarrow 3$?

Comment: @Adrian no, it's quiet the opposite

Comment: Obviously, it has relation .. you 'll be understand after this .. first find the value of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} f(x)$.. and then find the value of $f'(x)$ at $3$.. which is equal to $f'(3)$.

Comment: The start is good but this part seems garbled " So, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} x^2=a^2=f(a)=f'(x).$ "

Comment: perhaps yes, but my intension was clear..

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write the definition of derivative of $f(x) = x^2 $ for $x=3$.